# Multiple ORDER BY (get latest element) MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have the following tables : Radios, Podcasts and Shows. A radio has many podcasts, and a podcasts has many shows. Each podcast can be ordered by its history, and each show can be ordered by its publication_date.

I want to get all the podcasts associated with their latest show.

The query looks like that :

```
SELECT r.name AS radio_name,Pod.*,Sh.* 
FROM podcasts Pod 
  INNER JOIN radios r ON (r.id=Pod.radio_id) 
  INNER JOIN shows Sh ON (Sh.podcast_id=Pod.id) 
ORDER BY Pod.history LIMIT 5
```

I'd like to have a second `ORDER BY Sh.publication_date` but I don't really know where it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only the latest show for each pod cast, then you need some what to get that information.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT r.name AS radio_name,Pod.*,Sh.* 
FROM podcasts Pod INNER JOIN
     radios r
     ON r.id = Pod.radio_id INNER JOIN
     shows Sh
     ON Sh.podcast_id = Pod.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from shows sh2
                  where sh2.podcast_id = sh.podcast_id.id and
                        sh2.publication_date > sh.publication_date
                 )
ORDER BY sh.publication_date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

In addition to the "obvious" indexes on the join columns, you walso want an index on `shows(podcast_id, publication_date)`.

I am also guessing that you want the results ordered by the most recent *show* publication date.

Comment: That should work, thank you, except the fact that I then want to order each podcast by their history (it's another field to show their disposability)

Comment: I just noticed a little problem : I get multiple times the same podcast with a different associated show, I believe it's the where not exists condition that is going wrong, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @johnmalkovitch . . . For each `podcast.id` this should return only one show -- unless two shows have exactly the same date.  Either you have multiple names on a podcast or multiple shows with the same date.

Comment: You are right, I have shows with the same date, is there a keyword that I can use so I just select once a podcast id?

Comment: You can use something like show id instead of show date, if you want the id with the largest value.

Comment: I can't change the fact that I order by the show date, but maybe I should request twice to get each podcast and then each last show, because I have no clue how can I only select one show when multiple ones have the same date.

Comment: You can change the second line of the subquery to something like `sh2.id > sh.id`.  However, that will choose the show with the biggest *id* -- which may or may not be on the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several expressions delimited by commas in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT r.name AS radio_name,Pod.*,Sh.* 
FROM podcasts Pod 
  INNER JOIN radios r ON (r.id=Pod.radio_id) 
  INNER JOIN shows Sh ON (Sh.podcast_id=Pod.id) 
ORDER BY Pod.history, Sh.publication_date LIMIT 5
------------- Here -^
```

Comment: Yes but I want to retrieve 5 podcast (LIMIT 5) and with each one having the latest show. Doing it the way you described it, the query takes more than 1s, which is huge when it shouldn't take more than 30ms, so something is going wrong

Comment: @johnmalkovitch regarding the query speed, do you have indexes on all the columns that appear in the `JOIN` and `ORDER BY` clauses?

Comment: The problem of the speed is the following : when I do the request that @Mureinik told, I get the same podcast 5 times with 5 different shows for those podcasts (decreasing publication_date). I want 5 different podcasts (order by their history) with their latest show (order by publication_date).